# Showing protected page after login

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

So I'm very new to Laravel (and MVC frameworks), just doing a few basic tutorials to get my head around it.

After doing this tutorial: https://bitbucket.org/beni/laravel-4-tutorial/wiki/User_Management

I get to the last part ("Add Protected Page") and it just quite simply does not work for me.

This is what I've used via the tutorial.

```
// Routes.php

...
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('secret', 'HomeController@showSecret');
});
...
```

I've also tried:

```
// Routes.php

...
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('showSecret', 'HomeController');
});
...
```

Here's the other pages:

```
// HomeController.php

...
public function showSecret()
{
    return View::make('frontend/auth/secret');
}
...
```

And..:

```
// secret.blade.php

@extends('frontend/layouts/default')

@section('title')
    @parent
    :: Secret
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
@stop
```

Nothing happens, what am I doing wrong? All I want is a simple **protected page to show up on the user's home page once they're logged in!**

I am also showing the content section on my default layout:

```
...
<!-- Content -->
@section('content')
@show
...
```

Thanks in Advance
-J

Answer (score 0):

Try using Route::get('secret',array('uses'=>'HomeController@showSecret'));

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple fix, just had to change how I wanted to do it. I ended up putting the get('/'...) route inside my auth array and pointed it to the user's profile. Then changed my 'auth' filter to point to a welcome page where users can sign in or sign up.

```
// Routes.php
...
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses'=>'UserController@getProfile'));
});
Route::get('welcome', array('uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));
...


// Filters.php
...
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('welcome');
});
...
```